# Disable the past time in time picker in android

Tags: android, android-timepicker

How can I disable the past time in the time picker in Android? I have created the time picker so now how can I disable the past time in Android time picker?

Answer (score -4):

try something like this

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int cyear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int cmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int cday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        //start changes...
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, cyear, cmonth, cday);
        dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(new Date());
        return dialog;
        //end changes...
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: setMinDate in the type DatePicker is not applicable for the arguments (Date). I am getting this error.